# How do I display only the "View" tab for a specific webform and role?

Tags: webforms, 9

I have multiple webforms, In each of these webform submission results page I require only view page, when a non admin user uses the site to see the results, they should only see the view tab and the table, how do I unset the "Edit" tab in primary local task/tab for a specific user role and specific form and only display view tab in primary task and table in secondary local task. I did try with Tabtamer module although it provides me the options, I cannot disable the edit button for specific webforms for a role.

```php
function custom_module_menu_local_tasks_alter(&$data, $route_name) {
  $roles = \Drupal::currentUser()->getRoles();
  $current_path = \Drupal::service('path.current')->getPath();
  if (in_array("new_user", $roles)) {
    unset($data['tabs'][0]['entity.webform_submission.edit_form']);
  }
}
```

The above code removes all the tabs. How do I display only the *View* tab for a specific webform and role?